# PHP/MySQL - update rows with duplicate entries 

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have a database(about 3 million records) which has multiple/duplicate records with the same "email" in database and I would like to leave a single row with its default status(0) and update "status=5" for the rest of duplicates. 
 Please note that not all the records have duplicates. The email addresses are stored encoded in base64.

Comment: Is there a column that is unique for each row? like a primary key?

Comment: yes , I have id which is autoincrement

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UPDATE tbl
JOIN (
    SELECT email, MIN(ID) minID
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) t2 ON tbl.email = t2.email AND tbl.id != t2.minID
SET tbl.status = 5
```

Comment: ok.. I run the query .. any idea how much time may take to update 3 mil. records ?

Comment: @michael Is there index on `email`? If not your in for a loong time